# Moving Spring boot web application in tomcat 8

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I made a little web app with Spring Boot with web MVC, it is working fine if I run it by deploying the war or if I run it directly from STS. The problem is that my application is always run with his appname as context app (something like "localhost:8080/appname/") and I can't change it. I tried to write a web.xml with dispater-config.xml but, even if the server recognize it, the path is not changed. I tried to write the method in the SpringBootServletInitializer and setting the path, but it is not working too. I also tried to add a META-INF/context.xml in the webapp folder trought STS (project->src->webapp->META-INF->context.xml) but it's not working too. I am just going crazy with, what should i do to change the app's context path? Thanks

EDIT: I would mount my app in the root context of tomcat

Answer (score 1):

It's built in, in eclipse (STS). I suggest using a stand alone tomcat and not the integrated eclipse tomcat and deploy the war on your stand alone tomcat

Comment: Using web.xml, Servlet 3.0 methods or webapp/META-INF/context.xml techniques are not workings at all. I would like to just run my app trought STS and see it in the root context of server. I need it for a project work done with 20 persons, and i can't change everything in all the machines

Comment: @Neo87 The answer that Michaël provided should do the trick though. I also understand that you can't change everything when working with 20 people, but your question said "I made a little web app". For a little web app this should work just fine.

Comment: @GlennVanSchil the problem seems to be tomcat that just doesn't parse in any way my configuration. If i deploy in the stand alone tomcat, it doesn't deploy my app in the context root :(

Comment: @Neo87 in that case the problem probably is not the Tomcat but your configuration

Comment: I found something in tomcat docs that said root is locked... I had to give the project without root path :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the context path as a parameter to your `@RequestMapping` annotation, like this: `@RequestMapping("/helloworld")`

Comment: Thx for the answer, i added a new info cause i understand i made it ambiguous. I would to mount my app in the tomcat 8 root context, while i run my it from STS ide. I knew yet the way to move controllers trought application paths :)